# Android Numaric Dialpad Customization

Tags: android

I need to customize the dial pad for numbers is it possible i can add my won functionality in dial pad. Like I want to add a button when user click on that button I shift the user to a specified Activity.

Comment: you can't customize the dial pad as well as soft keyboard !